# Android Studio Default Junit Runner

Tags: android, junit4, junit5, kotlintest

i'm trying to writing test.
I have:

- Android Studio 3.1.4,
- Gradle 4.7
- io.kotlintest:kotlintest-runner-junit4:3.1.9

When i run my test via green arrow i see:

```
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: ioke.tinkoff.ru.higos.bridge.AIADynamicPropertiesObjectTest
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:71)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:70)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.lambda$resolveSelectors$2(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:59)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:58)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.resolveDiscoveryRequest(JupiterTestEngine.java:68)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:82)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:48)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

Aug 22, 2018 7:50:04 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: ioke.tinkoff.ru.higos.bridge.AIADynamicPropertiesObjectTest
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:71)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:70)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:30)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.collectTestClasses(VintageDiscoverer.java:64)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:51)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:82)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:48)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

Aug 22, 2018 7:50:04 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: ioke.tinkoff.ru.higos.bridge.AIADynamicPropertiesObjectTest
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:71)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:70)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.lambda$resolveSelectors$2(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:59)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1251)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:58)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.resolveDiscoveryRequest(JupiterTestEngine.java:68)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:61)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:65)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

Aug 22, 2018 7:50:04 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: ioke.tinkoff.ru.higos.bridge.AIADynamicPropertiesObjectTest
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:71)
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:70)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1376)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:30)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.collectTestClasses(VintageDiscoverer.java:64)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.discovery.VintageDiscoverer.discover(VintageDiscoverer.java:51)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.discover(VintageTestEngine.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverEngineRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:130)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discoverRoot(DefaultLauncher.java:117)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:65)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)
```

But when i run via cli-gradle task :test everything is fine.

How can i get the same behaviour when i run my test via green arrow in gui?

Comment: can you post the code of your test?